# Why did Alaric agree to Hope's request?

Tags: legacies

At the end of the first season of *Legacies*, a sequel series to *The Vampire Diaries*,

> Hope jumps into Malivore in an attempt to kill it

Previously, she's asked Alaric to destroy all the records that he and his family have of her, which he agrees to do. What I don't understand is *what* his motivation behind doing this is, though.

Obviously, she wants to be entirely forgotten. But in terms of his own motivations, why does Alaric go along with this, and try to erase<sup>1</sup> all evidence of her? Does he think it will help keep them safe from Triad? Be better for them emotionally? For that matter, why would he assume that she was even *correct* in thinking that she would be forgotten, given that her plan was to kill Malivore (which one might imagine would reverse its memory effects) and she demonstrated immunity to the effects of Malivore mud previously (so it wouldn't even be clear that it would work on her)?<sup>2</sup>

In short, what is his reasoning behind doing what Hope requests at all?

<sub>1: It may not even be sufficient, if any of the many *other* people at the school who knew her have photos of her on their phones, or talk about her in their diaries or emails, or they're in the newspaper from her winning the Miss Mystic Falls competition, or if Triad has any, or....</sub>

<sub>2: And indeed she seems to be coming back next season.</sub>